# Error call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback when using image_size_names_choose

Tags: php, functions, actions

I'm using the example from [add_image_size() | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/) to try to add custom image sizes to the admin media selector.

```
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'your-custom-size' => __( 'Your Custom Size Name' ),
    ) );
}
```

But I'm getting a PHP Warning:

> call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
>   function 'my_custom_sizes' not found or invalid function name

and the media size selector is empty:

[image: media size selector]

The answers to
[Adding custom image size to the media image editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200108/adding-custom-image-size-to-the-media-image-editor/226881#226881)
and
[add_image_size and add_filter('image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_image_sizes') not working with wordpress 3.5.2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/103995/add-image-size-and-add-filterimage-size-names-choose-my-custom-image-sizes) don't work.

I'm using the filter and `add_image_size` inside `after_setup_theme`; see below. I've tried it outside with no luck. Thumbnails are being generated, and regenerating thumbs works, too.

What is breaking?

```
function setup()
{

// other code


add_image_size( 'banner-ad', 655, 100, true );
add_image_size( 'banner-rectangle', 655, 250, true );


add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'banner-ad' => __( 'Banner Ad' ),
        'banner-rectangle' => __( 'Banner Rectangle' ),
    ) );
}



// other code
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\setup');
```

Comment: It might just be the copy/paste but I think you're missing a `}` after the function. Assuming that it's supposed to be insde the `setup()` function.

Comment: Thanks, that was missing; but that would cause a fatal error, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a hook callback function inside another function.

You've defined `my_custom_sizes()` inside `setup()`, which means that `my_custom_sizes()` cannot be called outside of the scope of `setup()`. This is a problem because the hook, `image_size_names_choose`, is not run inside your `setup()` function. You need to define your callback in the global scope:

```
function setup()
{
    add_image_size( 'banner-ad', 655, 100, true );
    add_image_size( 'banner-rectangle', 655, 250, true );

}
add_action('after_setup_theme', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\setup');

function my_custom_sizes( $sizes )
{
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'banner-ad' => __( 'Banner Ad' ),
        'banner-rectangle' => __( 'Banner Rectangle' ),
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\my_custom_sizes' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try defining the `my_custom_sizes()` function outside of the `setup()` function.

I'm pretty sure that the `my_custom_sizes()` function is only available in the scope of the `setup()` function - which has already been called before the `image_size_names_choose` filter is fired and so it's not available to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function my_custom_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'banner-ad' => __( 'Banner Ad' ),
        'banner-rectangle' => __( 'Banner Rectangle' ),
    ) );
}
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_sizes' );


function setup()
{

// other code


add_image_size( 'banner-ad', 655, 100, true );
add_image_size( 'banner-rectangle', 655, 250, true );



// other code
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\setup');
```